# How to relate 2 users table with one login table

Tags: relational-database

What are the best way to link the tables, who should be the FK or PK, or should i create another auto increment PK attribute for student and teacher table then make the user id in the table as FK.

p/s: I cannot post image since i need 10 reputation to do so..hmmmm

Comment: Type the information into your message, you don't need an image. Although you could have given a link to an image. But don't do that unless you also give the information the image gives, in text. PS You do not need to declare contraints to query. PK & FK declations just let the DBMS disallow updates to impossible database states. A PK says a set of columns are unique. A FK says subrows for a list of columns have to appear as subrows for some other list of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column with named userType, and check username,password and userType whether it is teacher or student

```
CREATE TABLE login(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
role VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

for more explanation click  [here](http://www.techyari.in/2014/10/multi-user-role-based-login-in-php-with-mysql.html)